# Strange MYSQL bind param error

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error in my logs, it doesn't seem to do anything/stop it working, but i'd like to know what it is on about.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with my `bind_param` and statement? I've tried adding `s` (removing the `s` ) removing the variables and it just keeps popping up.

> [Mon Jun 19 20:37:53.363632 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 41665] [client 5.69.190.95:57872] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/tools/public_html/test/phpfiles/databaseclass.php on line 79, referer: http://tools.cidetech.co.uk/test/domaindiagnostics.php?userInput=mmorpg.com
>   [Mon Jun 19 20:37:53.363724 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 41665] [client 5.69.190.95:57872] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/tools/public_html/test/phpfiles/databaseclass.php on line 117, referer: http://tools.cidetech.co.uk/test/domaindiagnostics.php?userInput=mmorpg.com
>   [Mon Jun 19 20:40:45.864311 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 42276] [client 5.69.190.95:57885] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared sta

This is the code it refers to -

Line 79 -

```
function searchData()
{
  $servername = $this->servername;
  $username = $this->username;
  $password = $this->password;
  $dbname = $this->dbname;
  #Opens the MYSQL Connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn)
    {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ##Prepares the statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dns WHERE domain LIKE '$this->domainname' ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$this->domainname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

117

```
## Function display search results
function displaySearchResults($idArray)
{
  $servername = $this->servername;
  $username = $this->username;
  $password = $this->password;
  $dbname = $this->dbname;
  #Opens the MYSQL Connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn)
    {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ## Begining of formatting of drop down table
    echo "<table class='table table-condensed'>";
     echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>Time</th>";
          echo "</tr>";
          ##Loops through all the matching ID's
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($idArray); $i++)
    {
        $id = $idArray[$i];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dns WHERE id LIKE '$id' ");
          $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
            $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->get_result();
              ## For ever matching ID it prints out the date/time into the drop do
```

Comment: That is not how you bind parameters. The bind_param replaces the ?'s in your query.

Comment: When in doubt, start by [Reading the Flippin Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: You shouldn't execute the same query multiple times. Build the query dynamically. Also if it is an exact match use `=`, not `like`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dns WHERE domain LIKE ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$this->domainname);
```

You do a question mark in the string and it inserts it. That is how it works. Try that at line 79 instead of what you put